# Wait for read lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How can I wait for a lock before checking it?

Basically, I want to cache a list in a private variable. I only populate that list every once and a while, the other 99.999999% of the time, I want to read it, so I don't want to lock every time I read.

```
public class SomeServlet extends CustomServlet {

    private static Object locker;
    private static List<String> someList;

    // moderately heavy populate, not called very often
    private void populateList() {
        // lock
        someList.clear();
        someList.addAll(getTheListStuff());
        // unlock
    }

    public void doGetLikeMethod(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
         // looking at some sort of method to check for the lock 
         // and wait for it, preferably with a timeout

         if(!locker.isLocked(1000) && somelist.isEmpty()) {
             populateList();
         }

        // the lock is present far less than 0.01% of the time this is checked
    }

    public void updateSomeList() {
       populateList(); // populate list for some other reason
    }
}
```

This is in a servlet and is not using a public framework. Our lead is very protective of adding any extra libraries, so I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. We have all the apache and java.util stuff. I'm not sure if I should use some sort of `sychronized`, `ReadWriteLock`, `ReentReadWriteLock`, or `Lock`.

I think I explained this well enough. Let me know if I need to clarify anything. I may be approaching this entirely wrong.

Comment: Locking an uncontested mutex should pretty lightweight, so I do not think this optimization is needed.

Comment: Just synchronize on locker for both reads and writes.  Java monitors don't give you some kind of faster "read lock" functionality, even if that would be better (in reality it would be a good way to introduce subtle bugs)

Comment: (Also: are you sure you want static variables there?  Seems like a per-servlet-instance kind of state you are trying to store...  might be better to use instance members / servlet lifecycle hooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  Multiple threads can hold the read lock at a time, as long as no write is going on, so it satisfies your efficiency desires.  Only a single thread can hold the write lock at a time, and only when no threads hold the read lock, so that ensures consistency between writes and reads.  You probably want to set fairness on, so that write threads will eventually be able to do their writes even when there is constant contention for reads.

Comment: Interesting that someone would downvote this.  Without leaving a comment, I can only assume you don't know enough about threading to understand that this is exactly the use case that ReadWriteLock is designed for.

Comment: You're completely right. I also don't know the reason of the downvote

Comment: I did not downvote, but based on the OP question as stated RW-lock would not be needed here, and would be a waste of resources.

Comment: @SergeyA I think it's clear the original poster is looking for some mechanism to synchronize reads and writes where reads predominate.  That requires some kind of locking.  ReadWriteLock is the obvious one, though the other answer suggesting copy on write could also work depending on the application.

Comment: @SergeyA I guess I considered the fact that the class has "Servlet" in its name to be a hint.  Also "multithreading" in the tags.  Although I suppose one could theoretically create a servlet container with only one servlet thread.

Answer (score 2):

from [http://tutorials.jenkov.com/](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/readwritelock.html)

> The rules by which a thread is allowed to lock the ReadWriteLock
>   either for reading or writing the guarded resource, are as follows:
>
> Read Lock     If no threads have locked the ReadWriteLock for writing, 
>   and no thread have requested a write lock (but not yet obtained it). 
>   Thus, multiple threads can lock the lock for reading.
>
> Write Lock    If
>   no threads are reading or writing.  Thus, only one thread at a time
>   can lock the lock for writing.

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();


readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

    // multiple readers can enter this section
    // if not locked for writing, and not writers waiting
    // to lock for writing.

readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();


readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

    // only one writer can enter this section,
    // and only if no threads are currently reading.

readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
```

So I think it's what you need

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you are writing less and reading more you may use Copy on Write methodology.

I have re-written the code with the solution i have mentioned.

```
public class SomeServlet extends CustomServlet {

private volatile List<String> someList;

// moderately heavy populate, not called very often
private void populateList() {
    someList = getTheListStuff();
}

public void doGetLikeMethod(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
     if(someList == null) {
         //If updating is expensive and do not want to do twice in worst case include the synchronization and another if check.
         //If updating is not expensive ignore synchronization and nested if.
         synnchroized(this){
            if(someList == null) {
              populateList();
            }
         }
     }
}

public void updateSomeList() {
   populateList(); // populate list for some other reason
}
}
```

Comment: in doGetLikeMethod, if someList == null, synchronize and recheck someList to make sure two threads don't do the initial population at the same time.  Can synchronize on the same thing in updateSomeList too, if updating is expensive.

Comment: Yes, if updating is expensive why don't you fetch on startup.